# Legend Alignment in Vega Lite

Tags: json, charts, visualization, vega-lite, vega

I hope you're all doing well.

I'm conducting some tests and would like to know if anyone has experience with a similar situation.

I'm working with a horizontal bar chart and have placed the legends at the top. Currently, with the settings orient="top" and direction="horizontal," the legends align with the Y-axis line. However, my goal is to align the legends with the left margin of the chart.

Here's an illustrative image showing the current alignment. If anyone has any tips or experience in adjusting the legend alignment in this way, I would greatly appreciate the help.

Current version

[image]

I would like it to look like this.

Is it possible?

[image]

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

I tried the commands orient="top" and direction="horizontal," but it didn't change the position.

```json
{
    "$schema":"https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
    "description":"A simple bar chart with embedded data.",
    "width":630,
    "data":{
        "values":[
            {
                "Local":"ALL",
                "Ano":"2023",
                "Valor":27076
            },
            {
                "Local":"SE",
                "Ano":"2023",
                "Valor":14132
            },
            {
                "Local":"CW",
                "Ano":"2023",
                "Valor":6434
            },
            {
                "Local":"SO",
                "Ano":"2023",
                "Valor":1036
            },
            {
                "Local":"NO",
                "Ano":"2023",
                "Valor":2684
            },
            {
                "Local":"NW",
                "Ano":"2023",
                "Valor":2790
            },
            {
                "Local":"ALL",
                "Ano":"2024*",
                "Valor":55584
            },
            {
                "Local":"SE",
                "Ano":"2024*",
                "Valor":29507
            },
            {
                "Local":"CW",
                "Ano":"2024*",
                "Valor":11190
            },
            {
                "Local":"SO",
                "Ano":"2024*",
                "Valor":10961
            },
            {
                "Local":"NO",
                "Ano":"2024*",
                "Valor":2454
            },
            {
                "Local":"NW",
                "Ano":"2024*",
                "Valor":1472
            }
        ]
    },
    "layer":[
        {
            "mark":"bar"
        },
        {
            "mark":{
                "type":"text",
                "align":"left",
                "baseline":"middle",
                "font":"Arial",
                "dx":4
            },
            "encoding":{
                "text":{
                    "field":"Valor",
                    "type":"quantitative"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "encoding":{
        "y":{
            "field":"Local",
            "type":"nominal",
            "axis":{
                "title":null,
                "labelFont":"Arial",
                "labelFontSize":14
            }
        },
        "x":{
            "field":"Valor",
            "type":"quantitative",
            "axis":{
                "title":null,
                "labelFont":"Arial",
                "labelFontSize":12
            }
        },
        "yOffset":{
            "field":"Ano"
        },
        "color":{
            "field":"Ano"
        }
    },
    "config":{
        "autosize":{
            "type":"fit-x",
            "contains":"padding"
        },
        "background":"#fff",
        "font":"Arial",
        "axis":{
            "domainColor":"#cbcbcb",
            "grid":false,
            "gridColor":"#cbcbcb",
            "gridWidth":1,
            "labelColor":"#000",
            "labelFontSize":10,
            "titleColor":"#333",
            "tickColor":"#cbcbcb",
            "tickSize":10,
            "titleFontSize":14,
            "titlePadding":10,
            "labelPadding":4,
            "title":null
        },
        "text":{
            "fontSize":14
        },
        "axisBand":{
            "grid":false
        },
        "legend":{
            "labelColor":"#333",
            "labelFontSize":11,
            "padding":1,
            "symbolSize":30,
            "symbolType":"square",
            "titleColor":"#333",
            "titleFontSize":14,
            "titlePadding":10,
            "title":null,
            "direction":"horizontal",
            "orient":"top",
            "layout":{
                "top":{
                    "bounds":"full",
                    "margin":10,
                    "center":false
                }
            }
        },
        "view":{
            "stroke":null
        },
        "bar":{
            "binSpacing":2,
            "fill":"#135aa3",
            "stroke":null
        },
        "range":{
            "category":[
                "#135aa3",
                "#f47080"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go.

[image]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "description": "A simple bar chart with embedded data.",
  "width": 630,
  "padding": {"top": 30},
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"Local": "ALL", "Ano": "2023", "Valor": 27076},
      {"Local": "SE", "Ano": "2023", "Valor": 14132},
      {"Local": "CW", "Ano": "2023", "Valor": 6434},
      {"Local": "SO", "Ano": "2023", "Valor": 1036},
      {"Local": "NO", "Ano": "2023", "Valor": 2684},
      {"Local": "NW", "Ano": "2023", "Valor": 2790},
      {"Local": "ALL", "Ano": "2024*", "Valor": 55584},
      {"Local": "SE", "Ano": "2024*", "Valor": 29507},
      {"Local": "CW", "Ano": "2024*", "Valor": 11190},
      {"Local": "SO", "Ano": "2024*", "Valor": 10961},
      {"Local": "NO", "Ano": "2024*", "Valor": 2454},
      {"Local": "NW", "Ano": "2024*", "Valor": 1472}
    ]
  },
  "layer": [
    {"mark": "bar"},
    {
      "mark": {
        "type": "text",
        "align": "left",
        "baseline": "middle",
        "font": "Arial",
        "dx": 4
      },
      "encoding": {"text": {"field": "Valor", "type": "quantitative"}}
    }
  ],
  "encoding": {
    "y": {
      "field": "Local",
      "type": "nominal",
      "axis": {"title": null, "labelFont": "Arial", "labelFontSize": 14}
    },
    "x": {
      "field": "Valor",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "axis": {"title": null, "labelFont": "Arial", "labelFontSize": 12}
    },
    "yOffset": {"field": "Ano"},
    "color": {"field": "Ano"}
  },
  "config": {
    "autosize": {"type": "fit-x", "contains": "padding"},
    "background": "#fff",
    "font": "Arial",
    "axis": {
      "domainColor": "#cbcbcb",
      "grid": false,
      "gridColor": "#cbcbcb",
      "gridWidth": 1,
      "labelColor": "#000",
      "labelFontSize": 10,
      "titleColor": "#333",
      "tickColor": "#cbcbcb",
      "tickSize": 10,
      "titleFontSize": 14,
      "titlePadding": 10,
      "labelPadding": 4,
      "title": null
    },
    "text": {"fontSize": 14},
    "axisBand": {"grid": false},
    "legend": {
      "labelColor": "#333",
      "labelFontSize": 11,
      "padding": 0,
      "symbolSize": 30,
      "symbolType": "square",
      "titleColor": "#333",
      "titleFontSize": 14,
      "titlePadding": 10,
      "title": null,
      "direction": "horizontal",
      "orient": "none",
      "legendX": -40,
      "legendY": -20
    },
    "view": {"stroke": null},
    "bar": {"binSpacing": 2, "fill": "#135aa3", "stroke": null},
    "range": {"category": ["#135aa3", "#f47080"]}
  }
}
```

Comment: Davide, thank you for the quick response. In the snippet above, you manually adjusted the legend position using "legendX." Is there a way to do this automatically without having to manually adjust the position?

Comment: There is no auto left align to y axis line unfortunately.